# Can I manipulate values within mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm learning React and Redux and found following problem that I can't get my head around, I have a config object in store that may looks like this:

```
{
    general:{duration:100,strength:100},
    gameA:{strength:50},
    gameB:{duration:50}
}
```

Where general object will always be there and will have all properties, and it could have one or more game objects with all or part of overriding properties.

Now, games `GameA` and `GameB` are using `duration` and `strength` props so I can do:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        duration: state.general.duration,
        strength: state.general.strength
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GameA);
```

but as my store example shows I could have different setup per game type which I want then override general setup. Can I then do this manipulation in the mapStateToProps function?

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    let {duration, strength} = state.general;
    if(state.gameA && state.gameA.duration) duration = state.gameA.duration;
    if(state.gameA && state.gameA.strength) strength= state.gameA.strength;
    return {
        duration: duration,
        strength: strength
}
```

Comment: I think your code will work. In general I tend to avoid putting business logic in the `mapStateToProps` function. You could easily do that in the component itself: (constructor, render function or componentWillReceiveProps depending on what works for your case)

Comment: I wonder why you have an object with constants in the state. The state is meant to expose data that will change.

Comment: what is constant in my example? all values can change...

Answer (score 3):

Another pattern is to use `reselect` to compute derived values from state:

https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html#composing-selectors

Selectors offer the benefit of memoizing derived values which proves extremely useful given the sensitivity of react lifecycle methods (why make this calculation more than once if you don't have to?).

I find they are super useful for abstracting presentation logic from a component.

Here is a short and very simple example:

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  price: getPriceWithDollarSign(state), 
})

// selectors/price.js
const getProduct = (state) => state.product // returns { price: 7.00 }

// i find it useful to immediately identify selectors with `get` so I know its a selector
export const getPriceWithDollarSign = createSelector(getProduct, (item) => {
  // this will only be evaluated once for this specific item, future calls to this method
  // will return the value cached by re-select (until the methods input changes)
  return `$${item.price}` // item is value returned by getProduct
})
```

In your component, you'd end up with `this.props.price -> '$7.00'`

The beauty of `reselect` is in its ability to compose multiple selectors, making it easy to share and use other selectors within one another.

Check out https://github.com/reactjs/reselect for more information.

While usage of reselect is geared towards deriving values from redux state, you can use the library with any data structure / library / framework you please.